# Reading Parameters From An Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => news/edit ) 
        [1] => Array ( [Name] => news/show ) )
```

I have the following two variables:

```
$module = 'news';
$action = 'show';
```

I want to see if my array contains `news/show` or `$module/$action`

I can use explode here, but I can only explode one array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for this?

```
$new_array=array_map(function($x){
     $y= explode('/',$x['Name']);
     return array('module'=>$y[0],'show'=>$y[1]);
},$array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_search:

```
$array = array(array("Name" => "news/edit" ), array("Name" => "news/show"));
$module = 'news';
$action = 'show';
var_dump(array_search(array("Name" => "$module/$action"), $array));
// int(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just concatenate the strings before checking? Like this:

```
function doesArrayContainModuleAction($array, $module, $action) {
    foreach($array as $subarray) {
        if($subarray['Name'] == "$module/$action") return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```